# Flutter Custom Painter - missing offset in coefficient calculation

Tags: flutter, dart

first i transform my image file to dart:ui image. then i set sizes i will be using with this method

```
void setSizes() async {
  imgOgSize =
      Size(image.value!.width.toDouble(), image.value!.height.toDouble());
  double wDiff = imgOgSize!.width - Get.width;
  double hDiff = imgOgSize!.height - Get.height;
  if (wDiff > hDiff) {
    coef.value = imgOgSize!.width / Get.width;
    canvasSize =
        Size(imgOgSize!.width / coef.value, imgOgSize!.height / coef.value);
  } else {
    coef.value = imgOgSize!.height / Get.height;
    canvasSize =
        Size(imgOgSize!.width / coef.value, imgOgSize!.height / coef.value);
  }
  print(coef.value);
  // canvasSize = Size(
  //     min(imgOgSize!.width, Get.width), min(imgOgSize!.height, Get.height));
}
```

my logic is finding size, that needs to be shrank more than the other and using it as a coefficient, because if i wanted to use `fit: BoxFit.scaleDown` i would not know what the coefficient would end up being.

the image is ready to be used on canvas, but i also need to get a list of points.

here is how i get the points

```
GestureDetector(
  onPanDown: (detailData) {
    controller.editor.value!.update(detailData.localPosition);
    controller.canvasKey.currentContext!
        .findRenderObject()!
        .markNeedsPaint();
  },
  onPanUpdate: (detailData) {
    controller.editor.value!.update(detailData.localPosition);
    controller.canvasKey.currentContext!
        .findRenderObject()!
        .markNeedsPaint();
  },
  child: CustomPaint(
    key: controller.canvasKey,
    painter: controller.editor.value,
    size: controller.canvasSize!,
  ),
)
```

now the overriden paint function looks like this with `fullSize` being `false`

```
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  final imageSize = Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble());
  final src = Offset.zero & imageSize;
  final dst = Offset.zero & size;
  // canvas.drawImageRect(image, src, dst, Paint());

  paintImage(
    canvas: canvas,
    rect: dst,
    image: image,
    // fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
    repeat: ImageRepeat.noRepeat,
    scale: 1 / coef,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    flipHorizontally: false,
    filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
  );

  for (Offset offset in points) {
    if (fullSize) {
      Offset of = Offset(offset.dx * coef, offset.dy * coef);
      canvas.drawCircle(of, 10 * coef, painter);
    } else {
      canvas.drawCircle(offset, 10, painter);
    }
  }
}
```

result:
[image: img on canvas]

but now, when i want to export it with this function with image's original height and width, to have full quality picture (using `imgOgSize` instead of `canvasSize`)

```
Future<ui.Image> getImage() async {
  final ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
  editor.value!.fullSize = true;
  editor.value!.paint(Canvas(recorder), imgOgSize!);
  editor.value!.fullSize = false;
  final ui.Picture picture = recorder.endRecording();

  ui.Image genImg = await picture.toImage(
      imgOgSize!.width.toInt(), imgOgSize!.height.toInt());
  // ui.Image genImg = await picture.toImage(canvasSize!.width.toInt(), canvasSize!.height.toInt());

  final pngBytes = await genImg.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
  final buffer = pngBytes!.buffer;

  await File('/data/user/0/app/app_flutter/t1.png')
      .delete();

  await File('/data/user/0/app/app_flutter/t1.png')
      .writeAsBytes(
          buffer.asUint8List(pngBytes.offsetInBytes, pngBytes.lengthInBytes));

  Get.find<HomeController>().imageViewPath.refresh();

  Get.to(() => ImageView());

  return await picture.toImage(
      imgOgSize!.width.toInt(), imgOgSize!.height.toInt());
}
```

this is the exported `.png` result

[image: exported image]

am i calculating the coefficient wrong? or is there some offset im not taking in account? help please. i also can provide more code if something important is missing, let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

**edit:** this answer works for phone orientation `portrait`, not `landscape`, which somehow still does not work. therefore i'm leaving the question open if someone can help.

i calculated the size wrong.

this is the correct `setSizes()`

```
void setSizes() {
  imgOgSize =
      Size(image.value!.width.toDouble(), image.value!.height.toDouble());

  double wC = imgOgSize!.width / Get.width;
  ouble hC = imgOgSize!.height / (Get.height - appBar.preferredSize.height);

  if (wC > hC) {
    coef.value = wC;
    canvasSize =
        Size(imgOgSize!.width / coef.value, imgOgSize!.height / coef.value);
  } else {
    coef.value = hC;
    canvasSize =
        Size(imgOgSize!.width / coef.value, imgOgSize!.height / coef.value);
  }
  print(coef.value);
  // canvasSize = Size(
  //     min(imgOgSize!.width, Get.width), min(imgOgSize!.height, Get.height));
}
```